# Is the function $f(x)=\sin(x\sin x)$ uniformly continuous?

Tags: real-analysis, uniform-continuity

> Is the following function uniformly continuous?

$f(x)=\sin(x\sin x)$

Tried using definition of uniformly continuous and also the fact that if the derivative is bounded then the function is uniformly continuous but failed in both cases .Please help.

Comment: Did you compute $f'(x)$ and try to bound it?

Comment: The derivative, I believe, is unbounded

Comment: Indeed -- which makes all the more mysterious how the OP "(t)ried using ... the fact that if the derivative is bounded then the function is uniformly continuous but failed".

Answer (score 3):

Hints:

1. If $f$ is uniformly continuous, then we have $f(y_n) - f(x_n)\to 0$ for any sequence $x_n, y_n$ with $y_n - x_n \to 0$.
2. Consider $x_n = 2\pi n$ and $y_n = x_n + \frac{1}{x_n}$.

Comment: We have $|f(x_n) - f(y_n)| =\left| \sin \left\{\left(2\pi n + \frac{1}{2n\pi }\right)\sin \frac{1}{2n\pi}\right\}\right|$. How do we show that this does not converge to 0?

Comment: @Anu notice that $x_n \sin(1/x_n) \to 1$ as $x_n \to \infty$

Comment: Thank you! So the limit would be $\sin 1$?

Comment: @Anu yes ${}{}{}{}{}{}$

Answer (score 0):

let $$f(x) = x\sin x$$
Take $n$ a positive integerand consider
$$a_n = 2n\pi -\pi/2 \quad \text{and} \quad b_n = 2n\pi + \pi/2$$

hence $$g(a_n) = -a_n \quad \text{and} \quad g(b_n) = b_n$$

In the interval $[-a_n, b_n]$ of length $4n \pi + \pi$, we have $2n$ periods, in other words is $2n$ points at which $f$ takes $-1$ and $2n$ points in which it takes the value $1$.

Hence, the average interval is $\pi/2n$ and the slope of the secant line is $4n/\pi.$ By MVT, there is such a point with the exact slope.

As $n \rightarrow +\infty$, $f$ is not Lipschitz continuous in the interval $[0, +\infty[$

Comment: Why so complicated? Just differentiate $f$

Comment: @user251257 An bounded derivative implies uniformly continuous. Converse is false.

Comment: @MathematicsStudent1122 yeah, but the answer shows only that $f$ is not Lipschitz continuous...